# How to start long running process in Spring 4.x using @Async annotation

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I am working on one my first Spring (4.x) services which uses WatchService.take() to wait for changes on the filesystem. The running time of these services therefore can be quite long. So i added the method containing the WatchService.take() with  @Async

```
@Service
public class ReceiveService() {

   @Async
    protected void startService() {
      LOG.info("Started service ReceiveService");
      ...
      WatchKey watchKey  = WatchService.take()
      ...
   }
}
```

The service is started from within the PostConstruct of another component with the @EnableAsync annotation.

```
@Component
@EnableAsync
public class receiveServiceController{

    @Autowired
    private ReceiveService receiveService;


    @PostConstruct
    public void Init() {
        LOG.info("Starting service ReceiveService");
        ReceiveService.startService();
    }
}
```

I have gone through quite some blogs and articles, but cannot find what is wrong. When deploying the application both log entries are logged, but it seems that further loading of the application-context stalls. What i expect is that the invoke on ReceiveService.startService() is not invoked asynchronously and therefore i made some kind of error.

== Update 1 ==

I created a @Configuration class as

```
public class ReceiveServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "ReceiveServiceExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("ReceiveService-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Removed the @EnableAsync annotation from the receiveServiceController. And replaced the @Async annotation for the startService method with @Async("ReceiveServiceExecutor")
When deploying it the initialization seems to hang when invoking the ReceiveService.startService() method again.

Comment: `@EnableAsync` on a `@Component` doesn't do anything it should be on a `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Also there is no Spring 2.2 so not sure which version you are actually using (3.2?).

Comment: According to Mvn Spring 4.1.4 is used. Initially based my version on version numbering in the external libraries

Answer (score -1):

Two things were wrong;

First autowiring of ReceiveService in receiveServiceController should autowire the interface not the implementation.

Secondly @Async, although it is not explicitly documented in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async), can be applied to Public methods only. So `protected void startService()` had to be changed to `public void startService()`